# What will happen if I change apple id associated with Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

If I change the Apple id (email) associated to my developer account, will it affect Apps those are live? Are there any cons for doing the same?

> **NOTE:** New apple id will not be associated with any other developer
>   account. I mean it will be fresh apple id created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't affect on Old Live Apps, they works as it is. Only for new apps they contact on new Address for an old Apps they communicates to your old one.

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen. Apple Developer account will continue to work as it is.

Please refer the following link for more details:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667#otheraddress